# how to read querystring value via Managed Bean in jsf1.1

Tags: jsf

How to read  query string value via managed bean  in jsf1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentContext()
       .getExternalContext().getRequest()).getQueryString();
```

Put this in the action method or a phase listener where you need it. Don't put it in constructor.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/JSF_WEB_WFE/faces/index.jsp?confirmuser=checkuser&emailid=valid

This query string(confirm user,emailid) can't read by your code
It will print the null value

Comment: I didn't get your explanation

Comment: Dear Bozho, this is url contains query string and its read by a Beans constructor http://localhost:8080/JSF_WEB_WFE/faces/index.jsp?confirmuser=checkuser&emailid=valid. I used the code u have given in my bean. it is displaying null.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how the answer of Bozho didn't work for you, but regardless of this, I would suggest to let JSF do all the work rather than getting the "raw" `HttpServletRequest` from under the JSF hoods inside a bean. Make use of the JSF managed property facility.

First, add two properties to the bean: `confirmuser` and `emailid`, of course with getters and setters. Then, define them as managed properties in `faces-config.xml` wherein they are to be filled with `#{param.confirmuser}` and `#{param.emailid}`. You probably already know, the `#{param}` points to the request parameter map.

E.g.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>userManager</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.UserManager</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>confirmuser</property-name>
        <value>#{param.confirmuser}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>emailid</property-name>
        <value>#{param.emailid}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

This way JSF will automatically set the bean properties with those values.

Comment: Iam using Jsf1.1 .
Jsf 1.1 is not  supported  #{param} El.I want to fix  this  issue in jsf1.1

Comment: It's supported in JSF 1.1. Even more, this is independent of JSF. If it doesn't solve your problem, then the cause of the problem lies somewhere else. It's probably the same cause as that you didn't get anything from `getQueryString()`. Don't you have some weird filters or servlets in the request chain which manipulates the URL before forwarding or so?

Comment: This examples woks fine earlier i made  mistake.
Thanks Baulc

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by passing the query string params as `<f:param />` values inside your command button.

For example, given the following URL (i.e. a user clicked this in an e-mail, thus no backing-bean code has been executed yet):

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/resetPassword.xhtml?uuid=3d7844ba-5f4b-4de0-9595-fdcbdedad4dc&code=a2JITmEyamJhQ29HTVhyaHhhNnRqdXI3T1kyMldydU4=
```

**Your JSF code**:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{resetPasswordController.doActualReset}" value="Submit">
    <f:param name="code" 
        value="#{param.code}" />
    <f:param name="uuid"
        value="#{param.uuid}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

**BackingBean**:

```
public String doActualReset() {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String code = (String) requestMap.get("code");
    String uuid = (String) requestMap.get("uuid");
    ...
}
```

*Caveat: This was tested in JSF 2, but should work in 1.1. There's nothing here that is 2.x specific.*

Comment: `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestParameterMap.get('code')}` is clumsy. Just use `#{param.code}`. Besides, there's no `#{facesContext}` in EL scope of JSF1.

Comment: Good point BalusC. I've updated the sample per your comment. thanks.